# Android change background of tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Does anyone know how i can edit a tabs background so i have a red gradient background when its not selected and when it is selected a dark red gradient? also change the text color to white?

Comment: you can make custom drawable for this

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator("Tab Host 1", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.XXX)).setContent(intent_name);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
setTabColor(tabHost);
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
          setTabColor(tabHost);
    }
});
}

public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); // unselected
    }

    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#74df00")); // selected
}
```

Comment: thanks for this i'm getting a null pointer exception here  .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#74df00"));

Comment: try setting different color codes because i have used the same code and its running fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in your drawables folder, background.xml for instance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use red-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_red"
          android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- When not selected, use dark rebg-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradien_dark_red"/>
</selector>
```

Use the new drawable for your background.